# Are there method of post array form without model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is not duplicate thread .
My case is to send array parameter without model.  but other thread is send int, string parameter individual.

I know about how to post to controller with model object.
But sometimes I want to post data outside of model db and post in format object or array
How could I do?

View

```
<form action="/home/showdata" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="arr.username" />
  <input type="text" name="arr.password" />
  <input type="text" name="arr.email" />
</form>
```

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ShowData(Array data)
    {  
        return Content(data.username + data.password + data.email);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this without a model?

Comment: because, there are some fields that not be in database table.

Comment: What does the database have to do with the model being posted here?

Comment: sorry but I understand that  model will always be database field

Comment: The models passed to and from your views should almost never be database models, it's often fairly bad practice to do that.

Comment: @coder_rebirth, incorrect, model your talking about is only just for ORM (DTO). you can have a `view model` for your case for a `view` which you will map your data to.

Comment: @12seconds a DTO is not "only just for ORM" - DTOs are merely plain objects carrying data from one process to another (whatever those processes might be).

Comment: @trashr0x, yes i understand that, I just assumed he's using EF, or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different kinds of `Models`. E.g. `Database Models`, `View Models`, `DTOs` etc. So, in your case, the data you receive from the client is significantly different from the database model (which, by the way, is usually the case). This means you should create a model specific to a view, a `View Model`, then after validating the data, transfer that that data to the database model. For example:

```
public class SampleViewModel {
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And then in your controller:

```
public IHttpActionResult SampleActionMethod(SampleViewModel model) {
     if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
          return BadRequest();
     }
     var sampleDbModel = new SampleDatabaseModel() {
          FullName = model.Name,
          ProductId = model.Id,
          // ... some other properties ...
     };
     // ... Save the sampleDbModel ...
     return Ok(); // .. or Created ...
}
```

This answers just shows you how to do what you are trying to do. But ideally, you should NOT use database model as parameters to action methods anyway. And there are a lot of other things involved, for which I suggest you look into `Repository Pattern`, `Unit Of Work` (for managing database tasks), and `Automapper` (for mapping stuff, if you want. E.g. view models to models) etc.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Hello i would recomended you FormCollection

```
    <form action="/home/showdata" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username" />
  <input type="text" name="password" />
  <input type="text" name="email" />
</form>
```

in controller you can use FormCollection

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ShowData(FormCollection data)
    {  
         string username=data.GetValues("username")[0];
         string password=data.GetValues("password")[0];       
           string email=data.GetValues("email")[0];

        return Content(username + password + email);
    }
}
```

also if some html input has same name then you will get string array of their value.

Comment: if you really dont want to use model you can pass data with FormCollection

Answer (score 0):

The best solution here is to use a model. A model **does not have to be related to a database table.**

```
public ActionResult ShowData(Array data)
```

could be:

```
public ActionResult ShowData(YourModelNameHere data)
```

And you could define `YourModelNameHere` as something like:

```
public class YourModelNameHere 
{
    public string username {get; set;}
    public string password {get; set;}
    public string email {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I misunderstand for model to always be database model. Thanks you so much.

Answer (score -4):

First you need to serialize your data on form and keep serialize data in hidden filed and after post get this data from formcollection using key and de-serialize 
it.

Comment: This answer has got nothing to do with the question being asked. Also serialising data into a hidden field is completely unnecessary.